# Java generics: actual argument T cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, generics

I have a code like this:

```
// This class cannot be changed
class VendorApi {
        static void func1(char x) {}
        static void func1(int x) {}
        static void func1(float x) {}
        static void func1(double x) {}
}

class Main {
          static <T> void my_func(T arg) {
                  // much of code, which uses T
                  // ...
                  VendorApi.<T>func1(arg);
          }

          public static void main(String args[]) {
                  // call my_func for each type (char, int, float, double)
                  // ...
                  int i = 1;
                  my_func(i);
                  char c = 1;
                  my_func(c);
          }
}
```

What I need to do is to call every function VendorApi.func() for every type of argument from my_func(). The code posted does not compile, it shows an idea. How can I do it besides copy-pasting my_func() for every type?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for dynamic overload resolution - or something more like C++ templating. Neither of those exists in Java. One option is double-dispatch... a single method accepting `Object` which can dispatch to the right `func1` overload based on the actual type. Also note that you can't use actual primitives as generic type arguments in Java.

Answer (score 6):

You could pass `func1` into the method as a `Consumer<T>`:

```
class VendorApi {
    static void func1(char x) {}
    static void func1(int x) {}
    static void func1(float x) {}
    static void func1(double x) {}
}

class Main {
      static void my_func(char arg) {  my_func(arg, VendorApi::func1); }
      static void my_func(int arg) {  my_func(arg, VendorApi::func1); }
      static void my_func(float arg) {  my_func(arg, VendorApi::func1); }
      static void my_func(double arg) {  my_func(arg, VendorApi::func1); }
      private static <T> void my_func(T arg, Consumer<T> func1) {
          // much of code, which uses T
          // ...
          func1.accept(arg);
      }

      public static void main(String args[]) {
          // call my_func for each type (char, int, float, double)
          // ...
          int i = 1;
          my_func(i, VendorApi::func1);
          char c = 1;
          my_func(c);
      }
}
```

This gives you compile time type safety (you can only call `my_func` with `char`, `int`, `float` and `double` from outside of the class since the generic version is private) and avoids reflection.

Also `my_func` should be `myFunc` if you want to follow the Java method naming conventions.

Answer (score 4):

Not the cleanest answer, but it will do what you ask.

You can test whether your generic arguments class matches with any of the types that your `VenderApi` provides and then cast is.

**Code**

```
public class Main {
    static <T> void my_func(T arg) {
        if (arg.getClass().equals(Integer.class))
            VendorApi.func1((Integer) arg);
        else if (arg.getClass().equals(Character.class))
            VendorApi.func1((Character) arg);
        else
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "cannot perform my_func on object of class "
                            + arg.getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // call my_func for each type (char, int, float, double)
        // ...
        int i = 1;
        my_func(i);
        char c = 1;
        my_func(c);
        String str = "bla";
        my_func(str);
    }
}
```

**your vendor API**

```
//This class cannot be changed
public class VendorApi {
    public static void func1(char x) {
        System.out.println("i am a char "+x);
    }

    public static void func1(int x) {
        System.out.println("i am a int "+x);
    }

    public static void func1(float x) {
    }

    public static void func1(double x) {
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
i am a int 1
i am a char 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot perform my_func on object of class class java.lang.String
    at core.Main.my_func(Main.java:10)
    at core.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Comment: This works, but it will result in copy-pasting. Function my_func() is not one-line, so it will contain almost identical pieces of code for every type.

Comment: @GennadyProskurin that means that you need to refactor `my_func` so that  it becomes one line, and "identical pieces of code" are in other functions :). The biggest problem isn't actually this, but the fact, that this implementation is not type-safe.  You don't want a generic function throwing runtime exceptions complaining that the type is wrong, as it completely defeats the purpose of generics, you could as well just declare it like `my_func(Object arg)`.

Comment: "pieces of code" are not identical, but "almost" identical. They use templated argument, so all body of my_func() must be copy-pasted in every if branch with small modifications. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @GennadyProskurin, if you want an advice on how to avoid duplicating code in a particular case, you will have to come up with more detail about it than "almost identical pieces". If you prefer to just talk in general, than the advice to you is extract those "pieces" into separate functions.

Comment: ok, "almost identical" code looks like:

    func1(arg);
    func2(arg);
    func3(arg);

Where each func?() is just like func1().
I do not see how this changes situation.
The best I could think of is to use cpp macro preprocessor to generate code.

Comment: Instead of `getClass().equals()`, you should really use `instanceof`, which optimizes better and is shorter.

Comment: @GennadyProskurin did you see my answer below? It sounds like that api wrapper solution would work for your case ...

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use reflection and a mapping:

```
Map<Class<?>, Method> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put(Integer.class, VendorApi.class.getMethod("func1", int.class));
// more mappings here
```

Although you need as much code as in an if/else construct, this mapping could also be filled programmatically (you could run a loop around `VendorApi.class.getMethods()`) or you could read the configuration from a file. All in all, such a mapping is more flexible.

Now you can use it for calling the API:

```
static void callVendorFunc(Object arg) {   // no need for generics here
    mapping.get(arg.getClass()).invoke(null, arg);
}
```

And your method becomes that:

```
static <T> void my_func(T arg) {
    // much of code, which uses T
    // ...
    callVendorFunc(arg);
}
```

I did not take care of any exception. And - of course - the reflectional approach is somewhat less performant.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for can not be done in java. This is a workaround.

```
// This class cannot be changed
class VendorApi {
    static void func1(char x) {}
    static void func1(int x) {}
    static void func1(float x) {}
    static void func1(double x) {}
}

class Main {
    static <T> void my_func(T arg) {
        // much of code, which uses T
        // ...
        if(arg instanceof Character) {
            VendorApi.func1((Character)arg);
        }
        else if (arg instanceof Integer) {
            VendorApi.func1((Integer)arg);
        }
        //And so on...
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // call my_func for each type (char, int, float, double)
        // ...
        int i = 1;
        my_func(i);
        char c = 1;
        my_func(c);
    }
}
```

But i would advice rethinking your design instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change your `VendorApi`, your best choice seems to be wrapping it around into a generic call. This is similar to what others suggested but with less duplication, and also type safe (no run-time exceptions if the argument is of a wrong type):

```
class VendorAPIWrapper {
    static <T extends Number> void func1(T arg) {
        if(arg instanceof Double) VendorAPI.func1(arg.doubleValue());
        else if(arg instanceof Float) VendorAPI.func1(arg.floatValue());
        else VendorAPI.func1(arg.intValue());
    }
    static void func1(char arg) { VendorAPI.func1(arg); }
}
```

You'll need to change the definition of `my_func` to constrain the type parameter as well, and then, inside it, you can just do `VendorAPIWrapper.func1(arg)`. The problem is that `Character` is not a `Number`, so, to be type-safe, you'll still need two versions of the function, one for numbers, and another for chars, unless you are willing to convert chars to ints or bytes before calling.

Comment: "api wrapper" idea is interesting by itself. However it does not solve my problem, I should anyway do copy-pasting all the code in every if/else branch. This code is not one-line call of func1, it is some code which uses "arg" argument, so I cannot factor out common part (without "arg").

Comment: @GennadyProskurin sure you can factor out the common part. Just add it as another parametrized function to the wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
static <T> void my_func(T arg) {
    // much of code, which uses T
   // ...
    if(arg instanceof Integer) {
        VendorApi.func1((Integer) arg)
    } else if(arg instanceof Double) {
          ...
    } else {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply split your method into the generic part and the invokation part:

```
public class Main {
     static void my_func(char arg) {
       my_funcGenericPart(arg);
       VendorApi.func1(arg);
     }
     static void my_func(int arg) {
       my_funcGenericPart(arg);
       VendorApi.func1(arg);
     }
     static void my_func(float arg) {
       my_funcGenericPart(arg);
       VendorApi.func1(arg);
     }
     static void my_func(double arg) {
       my_funcGenericPart(arg);
       VendorApi.func1(arg);
     }
     private static <T> void my_funcGenericPart(T arg) {
             // much of code, which uses T
             // ...

             // the caller will invoke the right VendorApi.func1(arg);
     }

     public static void main(String args[]) {
             // call my_func for each type (char, int, float, double)
             // ...
             int i = 1;
             my_func(i);
             char c = 1;
             my_func(c);
     }
}
```

Note that your type parameter `T` is of no use here, you could simply declare the argument of your generic method as `Object` (or `Number`) with no difference.

This is conceptionally close to [Alex’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115755/2711488) but doesn’t require Java 8. But his answer has the advantage that the generic code can choose at which point to call `VendorApi.func1` while this simple solution only allows calling before or after the generic part…